# How can I choose where windows makes the "System Reserved Partition" during a clean install?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10, windows-installation

I have two disks, a HDD and a SSD - I want to do a clean install of windows onto the SSD, including the system reserved partition - but the installer doesn't let me specify that partition, and when I choose the SSD as the place to install windows, it creates the System Reserved Partition on the HDD - how can I avoid this?

further details: both disks are empty & unformatted (I let the installer do  the formatting)

I first ran into this issue with windows 7, but now I notice it's the exact same for windows 10.

P.S. - yes, I can unplug the sata cable, or probably disable it in the BIOS somewhere, but I am wondering if there is a less hacky/better way of doing it

P.S. #2 - I am not looking to delete it

Comment: you can disconnect the hdd, so the ssd, is the only disk that is detected.  It likely also has to do which port is being used.

Answer (score 1):

first let me know if you are using MBR or UEFI. If using MBR than fix is easy just create 4 primary partition in hard disk and let the installer create system partition and system reserved partition in the ssd. You can format the hard disk later to your desired layout.

Comment: UEFI unfortunately